# Substitute a matrix in sympy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sympy, numpy-ndarray

I'm working on a tight binding model for graphene using pythTB. I want to incorporate spinfull elements in the calculation. The hamiltonian for the rashba hopping terms has the pauli spin matrix vector crossed with the site hopping vector.

Initially I created a list of matrices and crossed that with the vector, unfortunately this did not yield the correct result (I think that after the vector cross product was taken, then the cross product of the matrices were taken).

Next, I declared 3 symbols 's_x', 's_y', and 's_z' and used those instead of the matrices in my pauli spin matrix vector. After taking the cross product I received the correct result. The problem I am having is that I cannot substitute a matrix into the variable symbols I added in. Is it possible to do this? Or will I need to take the cross product manually?

Here is some of my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pythtb import * # import TB model class
from sympy import symbols
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create list of pauli spin matrices 
sx = [[0., 1.],[1., 0.]]
sy = [[0., -1.j],[1.j, 0.]]
sz = [[1., 0.],[0., -1.]]
Id = [[1., 0.], [0., 1.]]
s_pauli = np.zeros((4, 2, 2), dtype=complex)
s_pauli = [Id, sx, sy, sz]

# create s_pauli without identity matrix
s_pau = np.zeros((3, 2, 2), dtype=complex)
s_pau = [ s_x, s_y, s_z]

ab00 = [ 0.5, 0.28867513, 0.]

sig_x_ab00 = np.cross( s_pau, ab00)
```

If I print `sig_x_ab00[2]` (which is the only one I'm currently interested in), then I get:

```
0.288675134594813*s_x - 0.5*s_y
```

After obtaining that, I wanted to substitute `s_pauli[1]` for `s_x` and `s_pauli[2]` for `s_y` by doing the following command:

```
sig_x_ab00_ = sig_x_ab00.subs(s_x, s_pauli[1])
```

And I get the following error output:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'subs'
```

Is what I am doing at all valid? Or is there a better way to go about this?

Any input is much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: `numpy` doesn't 'know' about `sympy`.  `cross` works because `np.array(s_pau)` is an object dtype arrray, and simple math gets delegated to the element's own math methods.  But `sig_x_ab00` is an object  array, not a sympy expression.  Mixing numpy and sympy is a hit-or-miss task; sometimes works, other times it doesn't.  It is better to stick with one or the other, not mix them.

Comment: In Python you don't define a type for variables.  Those `np.zeros(...)` lines don't do anything for you.  Look at `s_pauli` and `s_pau`; what are they?

Answer (score 2):

Let's run your code, but looking at each step.  Don't make assumptions.

I'm using an `isympy` interactive environment; That `ipython` with `sympy` enhancements.  I also imported `np`.

```
In [4]: ab00 = [ 0.5, 0.28867513, 0.]                                           

In [5]: s_pauli                                                                 
Out[5]: 
[[[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]],
 [[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]],
 [[0.0, (-0-1j)], [1j, 0.0]],
 [[1.0, 0.0], [0.0, -1.0]]]
```

This is a list.  The previous `np.zeros(...)` expression does nothing.  In Python we don't set the 'type' of a variable.

We can make an array from this list:

```
In [6]: np.array(s_pauli)
```

`s_pauli[1]` works because it is just list indexing.

And the added symbols:

```
In [11]: s_x, s_y, s_z = symbols('s_x s_y s_z')                                 

In [12]: s_x                                                                    
Out[12]: sₓ

In [13]: s_pau = [ s_x, s_y, s_z]
```

Again, `s_pau` is a list, not an array.  When used in `cross` it will be turned into an array:

```
In [14]: np.array(s_pau)                                                        
Out[14]: array([s_x, s_y, s_z], dtype=object)
```

Note that is an object dtype array, which is still very much like a list.  Some basic math works, because math like multiply and add are defined for the symbols.  But transcendentals like `np.log` and `np.sin` don't work on such arrays.

`cross` just uses multiply and addition, so it works with these object arrays:

```
In [15]: sig = np.cross( s_pau, ab00)                                           

In [16]: sig                                                                    
Out[16]: array([-0.28867513*s_z, 0.5*s_z, 0.28867513*s_x - 0.5*s_y], dtype=object)
```

`sig` is a numpy array.  It is not a sympy expression, and does not have a `subs` method.  Again, it pays to pay close attention to what is happening.

The elements of the array are sympy expressions:

```
In [17]: sig[2]                                                                 
Out[17]: 0.28867513⋅sₓ - 0.5⋅s_y

In [20]: s2 = sig[2]
```

subs with a scalar value works:

```
In [22]: s2.subs(s_x, 1)                                                        
Out[22]: 0.28867513 - 0.5⋅s_y
```

but not with a list

```
In [23]: s2.subs(s_x, s_pauli[1])                                               
Out[23]: 0.28867513⋅sₓ - 0.5⋅s_y
```

However if I make sympy matrix from it:

```
In [24]: s_pauli[1]                                                             
Out[24]: [[0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0]]

In [25]: Matrix(s_pauli[1])                                                     
Out[25]: 
⎡0.0  1.0⎤
⎢        ⎥
⎣1.0  0.0⎦

In [26]: s2.subs(s_x, Out[25])                                                  
Out[26]: 
           ⎡    0       0.28867513⎤
-0.5⋅s_y + ⎢                      ⎥
           ⎣0.28867513      0     ⎦
```

The substitution does work.

In general mixing `sympy` and `numpy` is hit-or-miss; something work, almost more by accident than by design.  Others don't.  `sympy.lambdify` is the most reliable way of making a function that will work with numpy arrays.

In this case I suspect you'd be better of using a sympy version of `cross`, and doing the `sympy.Matrix` substitutions.